# Is an answer considered link-only if content from a supplementary or nonessential link is missing?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers, broken-link

We all know what a link-only answer is: it's an answer that, aside from a link, has no other meaningful content and therefore cannot stand on its own without the link. Such an answer **requires** readers to click on the link for it to have any use whatsoever. The classic and most egregious example:

> Check this link, it will help you... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx

(By the way, what are we supposed to check the link for exactly? Link rot? Spelling errors? Ticks?)

Now, consider the following:

> To output to the console, you can use `Console.WriteLine()`. For an example of how to use this method, see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx).

This answer consists of two parts:

1. A statement of which method to use to output to the console (which is notably missing from the egregious example above — even the URL doesn't convey any useful information aside from the fact that it's an MSDN documentation link).
2. A link pointing to examples of how to use said method to output to the console.

Based on the first statement alone, this now looks like an answer to a question you would expect to find on Stack Overflow (let's pretend the question is "How can I output to the console in a .NET console application?"), which means flagging as NAA becomes inappropriate.

The reader doesn't have to click the link to find out which method to use to output to the console. The reader *does* have to click the link to see the examples since they don't appear in the answer — but only if the reader is interested in the examples.

Obviously, the ideal action to take on such an answer is to quote the examples from the link within the answer. But should this be required *lest the entire answer be deleted via the LQP review process*? I mean, the second statement could always be edited out altogether and the link problem would go away and the answer would still be an answer:

> To output to the console, you can use `Console.WriteLine()`.

And having the link die on us would be no different from making such an edit.

But does this warrant deleting the entire thing outright?

Comment: This meta post may or may not have been prompted by a recent flag, but it's one of the many issues I've been contemplating for a long time.

Comment: Some examples which I encounter which I have far more trouble deciding on than the example in this question are answers such as "Use libfoo to do this: http://..." Is this a link-only answer? Or not? It sort-of answers the question by recommending a tool or library which may very well fix the issue, but it's only a link... The "soft" guideline we have at vi.SE is to include a usage example, but sometimes that can be hard, as the usage can be really basic (like a single command) or very complicated. And does copying the basic example from the project's homepage *really* add to the answer?

Comment: I wish you could find a better example, the problem with an answer like that is the question.  If it is really that trite then, no, the answer is plenty good enough.  Just turn the keywords into a hyperlink, like [Console.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), ought to slow down the Red Button reviewers.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Any better and I'd be invoking the meta effect.

Comment: You could quote one that got deleted perhaps.

Comment: @Cody Gray: There is no question that the second example is an answer. The question is whether the second example should be deleted completely simply because the examples alluded to in the link are not present in the answer.

Comment: It seems quite obvious to me that it should not be deleted. It is a perfectly valid answer that stands alone. A link to *supplemental content* is never a problem. I don't mean to be rude here, but I just don't get how you really aren't sure about this.

Comment: The question is probably if examples are necessary for an answer? If yes I would say that they cannot be link only. However, examples are not really necessary for answering a question, unless the question asked for examples.

Comment: @Trilarion: Excellent point. I agree that is what it probably boils down to. You should flesh that out in an answer here.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I posted this for the sake of discussion mainly - if it helps, you can pretend I'm not the asker...

Answer (score 10):

The OP has what she needs to fix the problem. So it's an answer, but not a very good answer. [Check this link for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/166789).

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I think he intended for this to be a combination of the first two samples - more specifically a combination of a proper answer and a completely non-descriptive link (as opposed to a descriptive one).

Comment: Actually you should be voting to close as duplicate, except I'm not sure how we handle meta.SO --> meta.SE. So yes, this may be legitimate, although can you please replace "this link" with "this similar question on meta.SE".

Comment: @djechlin [Allowing straightforward duplicates to be linked from main meta to specific meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276854/166789)

Comment: I find that a less satisfactory example if so, @BoltClock, but, eh. My edit was a suggestion; it's not my answer.

Comment: I concede, +1, can't argue with good citation.

Comment: +2 actually - this answer is basically a quine. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

IMO, this answer (with link...  even without link)

> To output to the console, you can use Console.WriteLine(). For an example of how to use this method, see the documentation.

Meets this from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

> Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. **Brevity is acceptable**, but fuller explanations are better.

Bold is mine, and it's perfect here. The answer is a quality answer as is. It would be *better* with examples (for instance) copied over, but that's not necessary for it to be a correct, useful and complete answer.

The problem with terse answers is people (or enough to stir up trouble) in the review queues don't actually review them. They see the exact same signal the bot used to put them there - short + link - and vote off that signal, *entirely defeating the point of reviewing*.

I don't know how to solve this but I would really prefer not to ruin the experience of producing a terse answer. It's a pain point in a few areas of SO: we're not really sure what to make of short answers and **sometimes answerers get punished in random and harsh ways**, e.g. random auto-comments from the LQ queue, answer being auto-converted to comment, etc., that really defeat a lot of goodwill especially when the answerer really did take pride in producing something terse and valuable.

If we *do* want to punish them, there's far better ways than the existing mechanisms. But more importantly I think we **need to find ways to protect quality answers that happen to be terse** from the LQR queue and bot mechanisms that try to can as many short answers as possible.