# Flagging an answer because the linked resources are no longer working

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation

Is flagging an answer for moderator attention wrong when the embedded link is broken or no longer available?

[SAS - Allocating maximum memory for a hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242160/sas-allocating-maximum-memory-for-a-hash-table/14649455#14649455)

Both links are not there now, but my flag was declined.

Answer (score 5):

Broken links in and of themselves do not warrant moderator intervention if the rest of the answer is available. Anyone who is inclined can visit the Internet Wayback Machine and, if it's archived, retrieve the page and edit the archive link into the answer.

Only when a broken link renders an answer completely useless (for example, when the answer consists of nothing but "Check this link") is it appropriate to flag it for deletion. For most answers of this nature a "very low quality" flag will suffice; moderator attention flags are only needed if it's not entirely clear that the answer cannot survive on its own without the link.

See also: [Is an answer considered link-only if content from a supplementary or nonessential link is missing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318870/is-an-answer-considered-link-only-if-content-from-a-supplementary-or-nonessentia)