# Why was this upvoted (+20) answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6455902/870729) was deleted by someone other than the author (assuming a mod).

**I am just curious and trying to learn.**  Not a complaint, it wasn't my answer, I just want to understand the SO community and stewardship better.  (I have read [why and how are some answers deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).)

It seems the answer was decent, and upvoted (+21 / -1) at the time it was deleted.

I don't have the rep (or knowledge) to see the edit history or comments on why the answer was deleted, but it seems like a quality answer to me with a fair amount of upvoting.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Generally, saying "if this post/comment got acted on, why not this other one" will net you an answer of "no one saw/flagged/voted on that other one", which is not horribly constructive to discussion. Also, if you want input from people below 10k, a screenshot would not be amiss.

Comment: Sure, no biggie. I would say that it distracts from the main point, but that's me...

Comment: I think at 10k rep you can view deleted posts and also their edit history. If you don't see the link it's because the post has not been edited, but you can still see the history in http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6455902/revisions

Comment: Moderation in this community sucks. Have you ever noticed that of most of the best and top voted QA of all times, almost all do not follow the canonical "rules"? What can be the meaning of it?

Comment: @pietrovismara The rules and guidelines were different in the past.

Comment: @AndrewMorton [Not really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). Very often i see things like "This question was closed as too broad" but "locked" because the question has historical significance. This almost always happens with the most useful QA that i found on SO.

Comment: @pietrovismara: old, locked, closed posts is consistent with the view that the rules and guidance were different in the past. For what it is worth, that really is the established view of the community, and some examples of "what about this one" isn't going to change it suddenly.

Comment: @pietrovismara classic mistake some make, you can't judge old question / answers by the same yard stick used now. Historically the guidelines were different, so applying them now would be unfair. In a lot of cases the answers can completely break current guidelines almost to point of being LQ / NAA but they've stood the test of time, so routing through them now and trying to measure them with the latest yard stick is a pointless task.

Comment: @pietrovismara Back in the Old days, rules were different from now. If someone asked that question now, then it would be closed as a duplicate, since it already exists. But there are plenty of questions without code that get received fine.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Someone flagged it as a link-only answer and it was deleted by someone who was a moderator at the time.

I've undeleted it, because I disagree that it's a link-only answer. The first statement succinctly yet thoroughly answers the question, and the PHP manual link is really just there as supplementary, and not even essential to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock.  I've learned tons from you through SO and Meta.  I appreciate all your hard work!

Comment: @cale_b: Thanks, I'm glad I made a difference!

Comment: I guess I would like to see a snippet from the linked page included in the answer. Reason being that without the linked content the answer is just "No".

Comment: @Ashley Medway: Yeah, I see where you're coming from. That said, while "No" isn't a terribly compelling answer by itself... it's an answer still. A link-only answer wouldn't even answer with a straight yes or no. That's even worse.

Comment: And it is a yes or no question.

Comment: @MartinSerrano Shouldn't you backup your answer with evidence, which he has but that evidence is only valid as long as the link works.

Comment: @AshleyMedway, my point is that such a simple question is likely to have a simple answer.  Saying constants are constant and providing a reference to documentation seems appropriate.

Comment: @MartinSerrano but if you need a link to make your answer good or valid then you should include the content, isn't the StackOverflow philosophy to always assume that the link will go dead.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Adding the relevant content from the link might be good; that's why answers are community editable.

Comment: @Ashley Medway: I posted about that some time ago: [Is an answer considered link-only if content from a supplementary or nonessential link is missing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318870/is-an-answer-considered-link-only-if-content-from-a-supplementary-or-nonessentia). It didn't gain a whole lot of traction, though.

Comment: Someone coming from here edited his answer to add content from the external link, and it was reverted. Let us all remember the whole point of this Meta discussion, which is (was) whether the answer should be deleted. It should not; it's that simple.

Comment: @Marc.2377: To be fair, the edit added nothing that wasn't already in the answer. The quoted text even says "As the name suggests". Even a quote from the dictionary.com link would have been more helpful than the PHP manual, as at the very least the dictionary tells you what the word constant *means*.

Comment: @BoltClock Haha, indeed!

Comment: @BoltClock I completely disagree, if the content from the link adds nothing then delete the link all together. The fact of the matter is it doesn't "add nothing" it is the justification of the answer. So if the link justifies the answer than a snippet from the link should be included for when/if the link is dead.

Comment: There are some instances where a link like this does add no value, IMO in this case it does just add value. If someone is genuinely looking for an answer to this question is "No" enough, or will you next question be why? IMO a yes/no answer needs justification

Comment: @Ashley Medway: The text in the original answer is a paraphrase of the content from the link. I don't see a need to then duplicate this information in a verbatim quotation from the link that itself says exactly the same thing: "You can't change the value of a constant because a constant is a constant." That said if the link really does bother you so much, no one's stopping you from editing it out and doing away with the link problem altogether. I even state as much in the question I linked to.

Comment: @BoltClock I have no problem removing the link, having reviewed your other meta question I tend to agree with your points. It would be nice to get some attention to your post as I think there should be a general reference point for these types of answers as this is not the only one.

Comment: @Ashley Medway: Maybe I should have posted it under a different account so people wouldn't dismiss it as something that shouldn't have to be asked by a mod.

Answer (score 1):

The whole question is:

> Can you undefine or change a constant in PHP?

The answer in discussion addresses askers question. In fact even a simple `No.` would've suffice to answer this kind of question.